# Cannot connect to Windows server active directory lightweight service

Tags: c++, windows, server, active-directory, ldap

Am working with windows server I want to create active directory lightweight service user by c++ ie, By c++ using ldap connection. My server runs in virtual box and i set the network adapter to be bridged network and it connects to the network just fine.
Now when i used the code from microsoft documentation the ldap bind is not connecting .The error am getting is an operation error occured.

```
#include "atlbase.h"
#include "activeds.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    HRESULT hr;
    IADsContainer* pCont;
    IDispatch* pDisp = NULL;
    IADs* pUser;

    // Initialize COM before calling any ADSI functions or interfaces.
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    hr = ADsGetObject(L"LDAP://ABC.local",
        IID_IADsContainer,
        (void**)&pCont);

    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    //-----------------
    // Create a user
    //-----------------

    hr = pCont->Create(CComBSTR("user"), CComBSTR("cn=jeffsmith"), &pDisp);

    // Release the container object.    
    pCont->Release();

    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    hr = pDisp->QueryInterface(IID_IADs, (void**)&pUser);

    // Release the dispatch interface.
    pDisp->Release();

    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // Commit the object data to the directory.
    pUser->SetInfo();

    // Release the object.
    pUser->Release();

    CoUninitialize();
}
```

This is the code am using to check for successful connection. Any help will be really useful thank you.

Comment: Where in the code are you seeing the error? And can you give the link to the documentation that you're following?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/setting-up-c---for-adsi-development this is the documentation The Hresult returned is empty as there is no connection established.

Comment: Which `hr` is empty?

Comment: The AdgetObject which return the hresult doesnt seem to connect with the server os and it throws the error saying An operation error occured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking for a container (`IID_IADsContainer`), but the path you give it is to the root of the domain (`LDAP://ABC.local`). Try specifying the distinguished name of the OU you want to put the user in. For example, if you want to put the user in the `Users` OU, which is at the root of the domain, it would look like this:

```
hr = ADsGetObject(L"LDAP://ABC.local/OU=Users,DC=ABC,DC=local",
    IID_IADsContainer,
    (void**)&pCont);
```

You can read more about the format of the LDAP path here: [LDAP ADsPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/ldap-adspath)

Comment: Yes this was the issue to and as i was running my server on the virtual box it need some ip configuration and ADSOpenObject is the function needed here as i need to give the administrator rights and the getobject method assumes we have adminstrator rights. They didn't mention this in the documentation